# Density and Wave Speed

Tags: waves

For a string, the formula for wave speed is $v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$, where $\mu=\frac{m}{L}$. The greater the linear density, the more massive the string is per unit length, the more inertia it has, and the slower the wave propagates.

However, for a sound wave, wave speed is fastest in densest media. Why is that the case? Doesn’t inertia come into play as well, slowing down the wave?

Comment: The formula you give is for a string; for a fluid, you have $c_s^2=\partial p/\partial\rho$. So it depends on the equation of state in that case (e.g. $p\sim\rho T\to c_s\sim\sqrt T$).

Comment: @KyleKanos Is there a formula for the fluid that doesn’t require calculus?

Comment: If you assume an ideal gas, then the answer can be found online & in texts (i.e. someone else did the calculus work for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a solid, [the speed of sound is given by](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/souspe2.html)

$$c = \sqrt\frac{B}{\rho}$$

where $B$ is the bulk modulus, and $\rho$ is the density.

So contrary to your assertion that "wave speed is fastest in denser media", the same type of relationship holds as for string: speed goes up if the force constant (restoring force for displacement) is greater, and it goes down as the inertia increases.

An example - speed of sound in diamond (density ~ 3.5 g/cc) is about 12000 m/s; in lead (density ~11.3 g/cc) it is about 1200 m/s. While lead is denser, the speed of sound is 1/10th of the value in diamond. This is of course because diamond has lower density, and much greater bulk modulus (large force for small deformation).